# Meteor: registering users then autologin

Tags: meteor, account, meteor-accounts

I have a consent form to participate in an online experiment. Once a participant agrees to the consent form, I want to create a user account for them and add them to the Players collection. I do not want the user to choose their username (and I prefer if there was no password). There should not be login/registration in the interface, it is all done automatically.  My current code:

The `consent_page.js` has the following code:

```
import './consent_page.html';
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'

Template.consent_page.events({
    'submit .consent-form'(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call('players.addPlayer');
        FlowRouter.go('/instructions')
    }
});
```

The `players.addPlayer` method being called is:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Players } from './players.js';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random'
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

Meteor.methods({
    'players.addPlayer'() {
        console.log('I am in the method');
        const random_username = Random.id();
        const random_password = Random.id();
        user = Accounts.createUser({
            username: random_username,
            password: random_password
        });

        Players.insert({
            _id: this.userId,
            enterTime: new Date(),
            status: 'instructions',
            passedQuiz: false,
            quizAttempts: 0,
            needRematch: false,
            condition: 'control',
            consent: true
        });

        if (user){
            return user
        } else {
            console.log('no user')
        }
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to login the user automatically, as I am getting the following error:

```
I20170816-13:57:59.061(-4)? I am in the method
I20170816-13:57:59.248(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'players.addPlayer' Error: Meteor requires document _id fields to be non-empty strings or ObjectIDs
I20170816-13:57:59.248(-4)?     at [object Object].insert (packages/mongo/collection.js:478:13)
I20170816-13:57:59.249(-4)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.players.addPlayer (imports/api/players/methods.js:17:17)
I20170816-13:57:59.250(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1768:12)
I20170816-13:57:59.250(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:719:19
I20170816-13:57:59.251(-4)?     at [object Object].EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1135:15)
I20170816-13:57:59.251(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:717:46
I20170816-13:57:59.251(-4)?     at [object Object].EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1135:15)
I20170816-13:57:59.252(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:715:46
I20170816-13:57:59.252(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:689:23)
I20170816-13:57:59.252(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:559:43
```

The problem is `this.userId` returns null. If I replace the `_id` in the `Players.insert(..)` with something else, I can see in mongodb that the user is added to both, users collection and players collection.

How can I establish the connection/login the user upon the creation of their accounts so I can use this.userId immediately? and can I disable the need for a password?

Answer (score 0):

You're running this on the server therefore the user is not automatically logged in. `this.userId` will be undefined when you try to refer to it to create a player.

You need to invoke `Accounts.createUser()` from the client and then call the method to insert a player from the callback to `createUser()`.

Comment: I kinda need the accounts package in order to work with the user-status package https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status to keep track of users being idle, closing their browsers etc.

Comment: Also, it seems that when a client reconnects to the server (after temporarily losing connection), it will get a new connection with a new connection id. I want to be able to know if someone is returning.